# How can I target video links to one iframe?

Tags: php, html, iframe

I have one iframe and some link.
I wold like if I click a link it update the iframe.

```
echo"<iframe name='vidframe' width='100%' height='360px' 
    src='http://vidto.me/embed-3t83y76l81ml-640x360.html' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>";

echo"<a id='kat' target='vidframe' href='http://vidto.me/embed-32j7qctooybv-640x360.html'>
    load link2</a>";
```

I use this method but when I click the link it opens in new tab not in the iframe. What have I change to open the links in the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is somewhat correct but your video url is broken. I changed the URL to a youtube video for testing it works fine:

```
    <iframe name='vidframe' width='100%' height='360px' 
        src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/x_p0VGctlOk' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>";

    <a id='kat' target='vidframe' href='https://www.youtube.com/embed/HuQSWt-jj8k'>
        load link2</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to load to the full of the video in the new page maybe you can use this

```
   echo"<iframe name='vidframe' width='100%' height='360px' 
        src='http://vidto.me/embed-3t83y76l81ml-640x360.html' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>";
    echo"<a id='kat' target='_blank' href='http://vidto.me/embed-32j7qctooybv-640x360.html'>
        load link2</a>";
```